# IntelliJ Spring Bean Dependency Diagram for project files only

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, graph, dependencies, spring-bean

When you create a Spring Bean Dependency Diagram in IntelliJ, this massive dependency graph is created with most of the beans from the Spring framework itself. In fact, most of them are even stand-alone nodes in the graph with no connections whatsoever (see the bottom of the image).

[image: Spring Bean Dependency Diagram Overview]

How can you generate a diagram which only includes your project files and **direct** dependencies to your project files?

I am literally manually deleting all the unnecessary nodes in the graph right now.

Comment: Batch deletions are also not available. I have to delete the nodes one by one.

Comment: Feel  free to create feature request on YouTrack: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.